# Inserting a node before a given node in doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to insert a node before a given node. But I am not able to get the required output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{

    int data;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
};

void insert_beg(struct node** head, int new_data){
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = new_data;

    if(*head == NULL){

        temp->next = *head;
        temp->prev = NULL;          
        *head = temp;
    }
    else{
        temp->next = *head;     
        (*head)->prev = temp;
        *head = temp;
     }
}

void insert_before(struct node* next_node,int new_data){
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = new_data;

    if(next_node == NULL)
        printf("Invalid!!!!");


    temp->prev = next_node->prev;
    temp->next = next_node;
    next_node->prev = temp;

    if(temp->prev!=NULL)
        temp->prev->next = temp;
}

void printList(struct node* head){

    if(head == NULL)
        printf("The list is empty\n"); 
    else
        {
            while(head!=NULL){

                printf("%d\n",head->data);              
                head = head->next;              
              }
         }
}

int main(){

    struct node* head = NULL;   
    printList(head);    
    insert_beg(&head,10);
    insert_beg(&head,20);
    insert_before(head,70); 
    insert_beg(&head,30);

    printList(head);
}
```

Here I am trying to insert a node(with data = 70) before 20.

> Output: 30,20,10
>
> Expected Output: 30,70,20,10

Comment: Only read `main`, but I don't see how you can insert before the first item in the list without passing the address (`&head`), since the `head` variable is going to need updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `insert_before`, if the given node is the head, then the new node will be the new head.  So you need to pass the the address of `head` in order to modify it.

What you have right now looks like this:

```
head
  |
  v
------          ------          ------
- 30 -   --->   - 20 -   --->   - 10 - 
------   <---   ------   <---   ------
                  ^
------            |
- 70 -   ---------|
------
```

To fix this, include the address of `head` in the parameters to `insert_before`.

```
void insert_before(struct node **head, struct node *next_node, int new_data){
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   // don't cast the return value of malloc
    temp->data = new_data;

    if(next_node == NULL)
        printf("Invalid!!!!");


    temp->prev = next_node->prev;
    temp->next = next_node;
    next_node->prev = temp;

    if(temp->prev!=NULL) {
        temp->prev->next = temp;
    } else {
        *head = temp;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
insert_before(&head,head,70);
```

Comment: But what if the given node is not head?

Comment: @oldDoctor It will still work as expected.  Actually, your original code works as long as the given node is not `head`.  In the updated function, the first argument is always the address of `head` and the second argument is the node you want to place the new node before.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything right.But you are missing one thing In `insert_before` if the passed parameter `next_node` is head then you will be inserting a node before head. Therefore you have to make this newly added node a `head`.

Comment: But what if the passed parameter is not head?